# Is this tub pop-up drain stopper fixable/replaceable?

Tags: plumbing, repair, drain, bathtub, replacement

I noticed that the cap was not upright, so I tried to unscrew the cap to reseat it, thinking someone screwed it on incorrectly, and the whole thing very easily came out in my hand.

Looking down the drain I don't see the cross that I think is used to hold on to to unscrew the whole thing (I tried to get the camera's flash to illuminate it). And the removed stopper is missing two of its four supports (yellow arrow in the first image) that attach it to the drain's wall (not sure of the exact original number). I'm thinking it came built-in and it's now broken.

If it is beyond repair, do I get a new stopper similar to that one that was built-in, or will it require removing and replacing the stainless steel drain body?

One of my concerns **if** related to making a decision: those missing legs, could they puncture the pipe if they're stuck downstream? During installation I saw that it's of the flexible type. If it's a possibility, is that pipe replaceable without removing the tub (the tub was laid on concrete surrounded by bricks).

If it matters the tub is fiber reinforced plastic. And down the drain it's a white-walled PVC pipe, note as mentioned earlier, the crossbar came off with the stopper.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't consider that repairable. Enough metal corrosion has occurred that entire assembly is suspect and at risk of failure. The good news is that it's a fairly easy repair *if you have access*. If you'd like help with that, post some photos.

No, the metal parts won't damage your pipes. They're probably already out at the street.

Comment: What do you mean by "if you have access"?

Comment: Can you lay your  peepers on the hardware or not? :) You can't fix this from above.

Comment: Well, you maybe can, but not reliably. You'd want to replace the washer under the tub and make sure everything's tight and sealed.

Comment: "You can't fix this from above." The tub is laid in concrete, so I'm guessing from below would be removing the drain body and that is doable?

Comment: You may be able to thread the pop-up assembly out and an new one in. Without the crossbars that may be challenging.

Comment: "Enough metal corrosion has occurred that entire assembly is suspect and at risk of failure." -- Sorry just to be sure, if I get a plumber, that entire assembly can be replaced with the tub in place right? I'm not sure what you mean by "entire assembly", the thing that came out in my hand, or something related to the drain itself?

Comment: It's really hard to say from the gooey photos I have to judge by. You'd have to tell us what kind of pipe is down there beyond your camera's depth of field, and whether it looks like the popup bit is removable. They're not all the same. If you're not going to take a crack at fixing it yourself maybe just get some help on site.